# Does Java keep stream objects in memory after mapping them?

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection

Say I have the following stream:

```
List<Other> list = Stream
    .of(
        new MyObject(), 
        new MyObject()
    )
    .map(this::mapToOther)
    .collect(toList())
;
```

So after this is executed, I will certainly get a list of `Other` in memory, but I wonder whether the source objects (i.e. `MyObject`) are still "alive" in memory (I mean not yet garbage collectable)?

Comment: @user1589188 please clarify the moment of time you are asking about. Once `list` is assigned, everything but it's content is garbage collectible. If the question is about a moment before the second call to `mapToOther` the situation is not that trivial.

Comment: BTW, flatMap produces even less obvious behavior.

Comment: @Basilevs updated. yes, after the list is assigned.

Comment: @Basilevs but you got me into thinking, may be also as the stream goes through each source object, would each of them be GCable right after it completes the `map` but before all completed the `map`?

Comment: @user1589188 Probably not, but only because you are using Stream.of(). For a Stream implementation that only instantiates one (or a few) items just in time to feed them to the operation pipeline, any object created in the whole process is definitely GCable when the last operation that has a reference to it completes processing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not say what ´mapToOther` should or should not do.

So assume:

- mapToOther has the signature `Other mapToOther(MyObject obj)`, and transforms `obj` of type MyObject to a new object of type `Other`
- it does not keep a reference to `obj` somewhere else (maybe in some cache)
- it does not put a reference to `obj` into the newly created ´Other` object
- the implementation of the Stream classes is quite sane and takes cares not to create memory leaks

then the source objects are "garbage collectable" right after the assignment. If one of the above assumptions is violated, then the MyObject instances will continue to "live".

To answer your comment:

> as the stream goes through each source object, would each of them be garbage collectable right after it completes the map but before all completed the map

This ultimately depends on the underlying implementation of `Stream.of` and `map`. The [Stream documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) discourages multiple consumptions of a stream, hence there is no mandatory reason for the elements to be kept in scope right after they were processed. On the other hand, `Stream.of` uses [varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html), so all of the instances of `MyObject` are first created and then put into an array internally before `.of` is executed. The most straightforward implementation of `of` and  `map` might simply keep the elements in that array internally. So I would usually expect the elements are not garbage collectable before the assignment is completed.

Comment: Thank you and especially for addressing my comment as well. By "right after the assignment", I believe you mean after the `map` right? Not necessarily after the `collect`, no?

Comment: @user1589188; no, I meant "right after the full assignment." - then it is sure the objects are garbage collectable. Assuming the "map" for all objects is completed before the "collect" operation starts is a misunderstanding of what happens here. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/29915591  for a better understanding. It may happen that the processed subset of the objects are GC-able already in the middle of the collect operation, but it ulitmatemaly depends on the underlying implementation.

Answer (score 4):

As far as garbage collection goes it does what this does:

```
Other other = mapToOther(new MyObject());
```

That is, if `mapToOther()` leaves `other` holding a hard reference to your `MyObject` instance they will live and die together. If not the `MyObject` instance is eligible for garbage collection when you hit the semicolon. These things have been called nameless temporary objects or anonymous objects. Not every object gets directly associated with an identifier like a variable. But they can live forever in an object graph. That's one of the reasons circular references are such a bad thing.